# Redirect all output to a file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, stderr

I want to redirect all output to a file, like this:

```
Write-Error 'bla' *>>  '\\SERVER\s$\Test\test.log'
```

The problem is when I want to use a `LiteralPath`, then it fails as it's trying to resolve the path as a `wildcard path`. So this fails:

```
Write-Error 'bla' *>>  '\\SERVER\s$\Test\test[0].log'
```

When trying `Write-Error 'bla' | Out-File -LiteralPath` it doesn't write the error to the file, but only to the console.

Is there a way to have all the output in the file when using special characters in the file name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I've found it:

```
Write-Error 'bla' 2>&1 | Out-File -LiteralPath '\\SERVER\s$\Test\test[0].log' -Append
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [Start-Transcript](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849687.aspx) and [Stop-Transcript](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849688.aspx) cmdlets:

```
Start-Transcript -Path '\\SERVER\s$\Test\test[0].log'
# Your code
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: This is not really the way I want to 'fix' this. Is there another way with piping or redirecting output?

Comment: While it wasn't the desired solution, I got here through a general search and this is the perfect answer for me.